# displaying only specific format to certain browsers

Tags: php, html, audio, browser-detection

I'm about 6/10 steps into my experiment.

Now this is kind of a two part question:

Why on android 4.03 in chrome mp3 works but in android 4.04 stock browser it doesn't ? So what format does work?

How do I generate a certain file for one and not the other browser detection then php "IF" statements?

Here's my current code:

```
$dir = '../sound/'; 
$scan = scandir($dir);
$size = sizeof($scan);
$random = rand(1, $size);
$randomFile = $scan[$random];
$fileLocation = $dir. $randomFile;
$explode = explode(".", $randomFile);
$extension = $explode[1];
```

This is how I am displaying it in a html5 audio player:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="<?php echo $fileLocation; ?>"  
type="audio/<?php echo $extension; ?>">
</audio>
```

So how do I say search for random file mp3 for certain browsers than inject into the player then search for ogg or what ever other formats I need and inject it into the same player but only for certain browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to do any browser sniffing at all. Provide as many sources as possible for the audio, and the browser [will pick the one it can use](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-source-element).

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="<?php echo $fileLocation; ?>.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="<?php echo $fileLocation; ?>.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Oh, so  if I just add the ogg's in there the browser will ignore  the entire mp3 php line? Also do you know why stock browser on android doesn't work but chrome does?

Comment: @user1925845: Yep! And it’s probably because they’re not the same browser or OS and have different sets of codecs available.

Comment: Also that code you gave me I replaced mine with it and the player shows the play button shows I click play and nothing happens?

Comment: @user1925845: Did you make sure to set `$fileLocation` to the part without the extension?

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure exactly to what you mean. As in remove .mp3 and .ogg? Edit: okay I did that and it worked. My last question is how does the php know to look for ogg or mp3? I understand what you did but that HTML 5 statement was outside of the php statement so if a browser that wants a ogg how does the php statement $filelocation know to find only ogg?

Comment: @user1925845: PHP doesn’t pick which one the browser uses; PHP provides both URLs and their MIME types, and the browser downloads and plays one based off that.

Comment: Got cha!! Thank you.. Oh by the way I figured out why it wasn't playing on the stock browser. It seems the stock browsers needs audio/mpeg not audio/mp3 with mpeg it works on chrome and stock browser now.

Comment: Last question if I wanted to do the same thing with an image on the same page but search a different folder  how would I go about that what $randomimage code would I use? And would I just echo it?

Comment: @user1925845: An image doesn’t need the same considerations. You’d do more or less the same thing to pick them, and then write `<img src="<?php echo $pathToImage; ?>">` or something.

Comment: Do I add $pathtoimage to the list of arrays? And how do I search a different folder than the audio files?

Comment: @user1925845: Did you write that code? I would assume you would change `'../sound/'` to `'../images/`. And just use `$fileLocation`, and drop the `$explode` line and the line after it for the image.

Comment: I'm trying to do both images and audio I'm the same page. I'm going for a Pandora effect.

Comment: What I'm asking basically is how would I perform both audio and images on the same page? How would I scan images in a separate folder also.

Comment: @user1925845: I just told you how to do both? These functions aren’t mutually exclusive, just put one after the other…

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem repetitive I'm just making sure. So your saying all the arrays that I currently have just add them again under the current ones and change the $dir to the image path? I just don't see how that works.

Comment: I put it together some guy gave me the $explode

Comment: @user1925845: Well you’ll be taking out the `$explode`, because you don’t need multiple extensions or types for an image. Apart from that, it works because you have images in your image directory, that code picks a random one, and PHP prints the path to said random image.

Comment: Okay, so just repeat arrays underneath current ones. Remove explode array. Than add $pathtoimage=$dir than echo $pathtoimage?

Comment: @user1925845: Pretty much.

Comment: Okay got it. But wont the $dir get confused with the first $dir from the audio one? Thanks man!!

Comment: @user1925845: If you do them one after another, it won’t matter. i.e. pick random image, `echo` random image, pick random audio, `echo` random audio.

Comment: @user1925845: Do some debugging! Or post your new code somewhere else and put a link to it here. But maybe you should start a new question for the two of them together if it’s not a simple thing.